# Why does my anti-virus call this piece of code a virus?

Tags: c

My anti-virus identifies the compiled ".exe" of this source as a virus
"Gen: Variant:Graftor" . Can anybody explain why?

```
void main()
{
 float x=3.0/7.0;
 double y=3.0/7.0;
 int a= (x==y);
}
```

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Is this necessary?

Comment: @Cygwinnian Are questions like this necessary?

Comment: Maybe the hash just *happens* to match the hash of a known virus?

Comment: @Cygwinnian no it wasnt. I forgot that I wasnt on reddit, so I edited my comment appropriately.

Comment: @H2CO3 Are comments like this necessary?

Comment: @squiguy That's quite possible ;-)

Comment: That what I call taking a pessimist approach.

Comment: The question has code, asks a specific question about that code, and the question seems to have a specific technical question. It seems on topic to me.

Comment: It tries to warn you that you state yourself on your pc as a developer or programmer and as one who started all that by installing ide and sdks of prefered language it makes harsh environment for av to run with compilers linkers and such and wastes a lot of cpu time.  I mean literaly if I etc. download a subtitle for a movie that looks like moovie_dvdrip.exe, or .zip with exe inside, as someone who liked development, I dont need any av cause I can delete it manualy without opening and save cpu. Cheers!

Comment: I mean, an dentist without six or more front side tooths does not neceserily makes him a bad dentist when he smiles, but makes him to look like a bad dentis xD

Answer (score 2):

Well, unmanaged / native programs can pose security risks and probably your antivirus marked this as such. Antiviruses use heuristics - so the algorithms are aproximate, they tend to work on a "best effort" idea, and in case of antiviruses "false positives" like your sample is preferable to missing actual viruses.

Another possibility is the way you compiled your program, there are a lot of compiler optimization and some are related to security - so your program randomizes certain parts of the memory etc. Maybe the antivirus looks at how a C program is compiled and yours has no security flags turned on? Hmm...

Comment: I would expect this piece of code to compile to an empty binary. If there is any virus out there that contains an empty binary, compiled with the same compiler+settings, you have a direct hit for the file.

Comment: Another interesting behavior, when i add a print statement printing 'a'. It is no more detected as a virus.

Comment: Man, you're having fun with this huh? :D

Comment: yup, experimenting with code, is the best way to write better ones and it is fun :D

Answer (score 1):

About Generic Detections

Unlike more traditional detections (also known as signatures or single-file detections) a Generic Detection does not identify a unique or individual malicious program. Instead, a Generic Detection looks for broadly applicable code or behavior characteristics that indicate a file as potentially malicious, so that a single Generic Detection can efficiently identify dozens, or even hundreds of malware.

This is a false positive. These sometimes occur in every antivirus product because of the complexity of present-day malware and file compression/protection utilities that are used on both malware and legitimate software.

Comment: Oh. I was shocked when I anti-virus showed it. I was just experimenting with floating precision and stuff. Thanks for the information .