# I accidentally created a virus. Just how is this a virus?

Tags: c++, string, antivirus, virus, trojan

So i was doing some experimenting with strings, just to see whether i could store a string in a variable and then display the contents of the variable onto the screen.
Apparently, my antivirus wasn't too happy with that.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string boy = "hello";
    cout << boy << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

> Active software that may cause harm to your computer or data has been
>   detected. Detected: Trojan.Win32.Shutdowner.aadw

Just how on earth did i manage to do that?
I am a first year in computer science and enumerations are as far as we've gotten.

Is this actually a virus or is my antivirus being '*paranoid*'? Or in other words is it just mistaking it as a virus due to some loophole or another?

P.S. I'm using `DEVC++`

Comment: you antivirus is being paranoid. You did not create any kind of virus.

Comment: probably you've opened some virus infected mail - this SW has nothing special and defiantly not a virus

Comment: Now you've infected all of us!

Comment: Are you a bitcoin miner?

Comment: i doubt it's infected mail. the path led to the exact file i was making. however it being paranoid makes a lot of sense. thanks guys

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/993671/accidentally-created-a-virus

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7987712/why-does-avgantivirus-detect-an-executable-produced-from-dev-c-as-a-virus)

Comment: Valid question if you ask me....

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14864202/why-does-my-anti-virus-call-this-piece-of-code-a-virus

Answer (score 16):

It is your antivirus being paranoid.  Antivirus programs are largely based on byte signatures for known virus code (some also rely on heuristic analysis of runtime behavior).  Your program simply compiled into binary code that happened to contain a random byte signature that your antivirus recognized from a known virus, that's all.  It is not unusual for an antivirus program to report false positives once in awhile, especially on development machines.  You can add your source/output folder(s) to your antivirus program's list of exceptions so it will not scan them anymore.

Comment: **Unless** the compiler is malicious

Comment: @grasGendarme - the linker is also one of the usual suspects - all linkers are malicious:)